# Setting ellipse size property with max length to a textview doesn't show dots at the end

Tags: android, textview

I have got two textviews that are aligned horizontally within relative layout.

Im limiting the `max length` of first textview to 15 and if it is more than 15, i wanna set `ellipse size` property to `end`

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:weightSum="10.0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Form I Submission"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:maxLength="14"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Inprogress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is

1. The three  dots  at the are not visible when I use the above code
2. If I remove max length property, dots are visible but still it overlaps the second textview.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Jist give paddingRight to the textView 10dp and let me know..

Comment: still dots are not visible

Comment: give maxLine= 1 instand of android:singleLine="true"

Comment: yeah but still the textview is getting overlapped

Comment: can you show me ur error screen shoots!!

Comment: it works after adding `maxEms` thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxEms="15" 
android:singleLine="true"
```